# Unable to create connection to Grakn instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, grpc, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I'm trying to connect to a remote Grakn instance on AWS using the remote console. After I ran `./grakn console -r [ip address]` I got this error:

```
Unable to create connection to Grakn instance at [IP address]
Cause: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException
UNAVAILABLE: io exception
```

I can SSH into the machine and Grakn is running. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking the firewall settings - you may need to open the required ports (48555 for Grakn clients) to allow inbound TCP connectinos.